# Assigning a JSON object as string to a property in an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

This is the code:

```
var container_list = [
  {type: 'editor', id: 't1', placeholder: 'first section'},
  {type: 'onlytext', value: 'second section - only text'},
  {type: 'editor', id: 't2', placeholder: 'third section'},
  {type: 'editor', id: 't3', placeholder: 'fourth section', defvalue: JSON.stringify(formatted_content)}
]

const formatted_content = {"ops":[{"attributes":{"italic":true,"bold":true},"insert":"let's"},{"insert":" write "},{"attributes":{"underline":true},"insert":"something"},{"insert":" wonderful\n"}]}
```

This works flawlessly:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(formatted_content));
```

But the result of:

```
console.log(container_list[3].defvalue);
```

is *undefined* .

How could i assign a JSON/variable to a property in an object?
Thanks!

Comment: Look at your code. You define `formatted_content` *after* you define `container_list`, why would you expect that to work at all?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Maybe because i started learning react and javascript together and one of the first example i saw was a component class in which a later declared variable was referenced, so i though javascript evaluates statement such a lazy way? Since my question i also figured out that before ES6 this kind of usage was working. I though stackoverflow is platform for asking questions. :)

Comment: Before ES6 this *also* didn't work. Variables are available only after declaration. Functions, on the other hand, are always hoisted, so `(function() { var x = test(); function test() { return 'yes'; } console.log(x); })()` will work just fine). If you copied this pattern from somewhere, please edit your post to point to where you found that pattern, because I would be incredibly surprised to learn that someone managed to write code where this did work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap the sequence you declare these 2 constants. When you declare `container_list`, `formatted_content` is not yet defined

```js
const formatted_content = {"ops":[{"attributes":{"italic":true,"bold":true},"insert":"let's"},{"insert":" write "},{"attributes":{"underline":true},"insert":"something"},{"insert":" wonderful\n"}]}

var container_list = [
  {type: 'editor', id: 't1', placeholder: 'first section'},
  {type: 'onlytext', value: 'second section - only text'},
  {type: 'editor', id: 't2', placeholder: 'third section'},
  {type: 'editor', id: 't3', placeholder: 'fourth section', defvalue: JSON.stringify(formatted_content)}
]

console.log(JSON.stringify(formatted_content));

console.log(container_list[3].defvalue);
```